# Fixing an element with itertools.permutations()

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples of the form route_cost = [(route, vehicle, cost),...]. Consider that I have 2 routes and 3 vehicles, I want to find the cheapest allocation of 1 vehicle to route 1 and 1 vehicle to route 2. When a vehicle is used it can not be used again.

I considered using itertools.permutations(route_cost, 2) but this of course will consider permutations for every entry. Ideally, I could fix a route and a vehicle i for the route and sum over all other routes and vehicles not equal to the fixed route or i.

Comment: Are all vehicles available for all routes, or can any vehicle only drive on some of the routes? Anyway, a basic approach could be to consider all permutations of r vehicles (r being the number of routes), calculate the total cost, and take the permutation with the minimal cost. Of course the complexity would be O(v**r), which can get huge.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that computes the total cost of each of the possible permutations of the vehicles, then return the allocation with the minimal total cost.

Note that the complexity is O(vehicles_count ^ routes_count), which may become quickly prohibitive.

```
from itertools import permutations

# Sample data
route_cost = [(1,1,3), (1,2,5), (1,3,7), (2,1,5), (2,2,8), (2,3,10)]

# Convert the data to more useful types
routes, vehicles, costs = set(), set(), {}
for r, v, c in route_cost:
    routes.add(r)
    vehicles.add(v)
    costs[(r,v)]=c
routes, vehicles = list(routes), list(vehicles)

# Construct the best allocation
cheapest_allocation = min(
        (
            (vp, sum(map(lambda t: costs[t], zip(routes, vp))))
            for vp in permutations(vehicles, len(routes))
        ),
        key=lambda t: t[1])

# Display the result
print(f'The cheapest allocation, with a total cost of {cheapest_allocation[1]}, is:')
for route, vehicle in zip(routes, cheapest_allocation[0]):
    print(f'\tRoute {route}: vehicle {vehicle} (cost = {costs[(route, vehicle)]})')
```

Result:

```
The cheapest allocation, with a cost of 10, is:
    Route 1: vehicle 2 (cost = 5)
    Route 2: vehicle 1 (cost = 5)
```